# Convert Column entries in to rows pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data set as follows and it repeats the description for each state (state, num people vaccinated, percentage of population vaccinated). I want to make all of the description entries to become column headers

Currently column headers = Description, Data

Wanted column headers = State, num people vaccinated, percentage of population vaccinated, Data

Any ideas on how to do this?

Here is my current code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv("vaccinate_pct.csv",header=1,na_values=" NaN",index_col=False)
df=df[['Description','Data']]
df=df.dropna(axis=0)
df
Description Data
0   state   Vermont
1   num people vaccinated   424,323
2   percentage of population vaccinated 68
3   state   Connecticut
4   num people vaccinated   2,360,741
... ... ...
148 num people vaccinated   1,891,063
149 percentage of population vaccinated 38.57
150 state   Mississippi
151 num people vaccinated   1,144,438
152 percentage of population vaccinated 38
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Yes, this can be done. Please give it a try, post your code, its output and any stacktraces it generates, and SO can help you fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by pivoting the dataframe, but only after you set the index so that the indices repeat for each group of 3 values. Otherwise, Pandas will fill in a bunch of `NaN`s.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Description': ['state', 'num people vaccinated', '% of pop vaccinated',
                                   'state', 'num people vaccinated', '% of pop vaccinated'],
                   'Data': ['Vermont', '424323', '68', 'Ohio', '6145359', '52']})
print(df)

# re-index the dataframe to [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, ...]
idx_vals = list(range(0, int(len(df)/3)))
df.index = list(np.repeat(idx_vals, 3))
print(df)

df2 = df.pivot( columns='Description', values='Data')
print(df2)
```

Note that this is only going to work if you have exactly 3 values for each state.

Comment: Assuming a range index floor division would be much faster `df.index = df.index // 3`. Or with `arange` -> `df.index = np.arange(len(df)) // 3`

Comment: @Henry Nice. I've never done this before. I had a felling there was a better way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

If this is what you meant:

Your df:

[image]

Solution:

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame()
description_unique_values = df.Description.unique()
df_dict = {name: df.loc[df['Description'] == name]['Data'] for name in description_unique_values}
for v in description_unique_values:
    df_new[v] = df_dict[v].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: not quite what I want
I want state column to be filled with all of the states. Right now this gives me a column header for each state (1x153) table instead of a (51x3) table

Comment: Fixed, Try it now